# RSocket: Local and remote state disagreement

Tags: serversocket, rsocket, rsocket-java

Enough stable system handles ~5 thousand WS requests per day and the 1%(~50 connections) connections are closing on an error with the next exception: during the resume process, we have a disagreement during the frames removing.

Did someone face this issue? Any idea what's going on?

```
java 11
kotlin 1.4.10
org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-rsocket:2.4.0
   -> io.rsocket:rsocket-core:1.1.0
   -> io.rsocket:rsocket-transport-netty:1.1.0

15:34:05.998 [reactor-http-epoll-3] ERROR reactor.core.publisher.Operators  - Operator called default onErrorDropped
 reactor.core.Exceptions$ErrorCallbackNotImplemented: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Local and remote state disagreement: need to remove additional 194 bytes, but cache is empty
 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Local and remote state disagreement: need to remove additional 194 bytes, but cache is empty
    at io.rsocket.resume.InMemoryResumableFramesStore.releaseFrames(InMemoryResumableFramesStore.java:120)
    at io.rsocket.resume.ServerRSocketSession.doResume(ServerRSocketSession.java:153)
    at io.rsocket.resume.ServerRSocketSession.lambda$resumeWith$2(ServerRSocketSession.java:109)
    at io.rsocket.resume.ServerRSocketSession.resumeWith(ServerRSocketSession.java:117)
    at io.rsocket.core.ServerSetup$ResumableServerSetup.acceptRSocketResume(ServerSetup.java:137)
    at io.rsocket.core.RSocketServer.acceptResume(RSocketServer.java:356)
    at io.rsocket.core.RSocketServer.accept(RSocketServer.java:368)
    at io.rsocket.core.RSocketServer.lambda$acceptor$0(RSocketServer.java:350)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:125)
    at com.company.mdc.config.MdcContextLifter.onNext(MdcConfig.kt:40)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFirstWithSignal$FirstEmittingSubscriber.onNext(FluxFirstWithSignal.java:329)
    at com.company.mdc.config.MdcContextLifter.onNext(MdcConfig.kt:40)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoCreate$DefaultMonoSink.success(MonoCreate.java:160)
    at io.rsocket.core.SetupHandlingDuplexConnection.onNext(SetupHandlingDuplexConnection.java:114)
    at io.rsocket.core.SetupHandlingDuplexConnection.onNext(SetupHandlingDuplexConnection.java:19)
    at com.company.mdc.config.MdcContextLifter.onNext(MdcConfig.kt:40)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onNext(FluxMap.java:120)
    at reactor.netty.channel.FluxReceive.drainReceiver(FluxReceive.java:265)
    at reactor.netty.channel.FluxReceive.onInboundNext(FluxReceive.java:371)
    at reactor.netty.channel.ChannelOperations.onInboundNext(ChannelOperations.java:381)
    at reactor.netty.http.server.HttpServerOperations.onInboundNext(HttpServerOperations.java:544)
    at reactor.netty.http.server.WebsocketServerOperations.onInboundNext(WebsocketServerOperations.java:161)
    at reactor.netty.channel.ChannelOperationsHandler.channelRead(ChannelOperationsHandler.java:94)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:324)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:296)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1410)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:919)
    at io.netty.channel.epoll.AbstractEpollStreamChannel$EpollStreamUnsafe.epollInReady(AbstractEpollStreamChannel.java:795)
    at io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.processReady(EpollEventLoop.java:480)
    at io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.run(EpollEventLoop.java:378)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:989)
    at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

Comment: This should possibly be raised as a project bug.

Comment: yup. sounds like a bug to report. @eugene-maksymets Can you do that for us, please?

Comment: The issue was created in the repo(https://github.com/rsocket/rsocket-java/issues/973)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That was a bug in the rsoket library. The issue is already fixed
https://github.com/rsocket/rsocket-java/issues/973